# Access module configuration value in a block

Tags: 8, blocks

I am trying to create a custom module which creates a block, which the user should be able to place on his website.

At it's simplest, the block should contain a set of values, which were selected when the module was configured in the configuration. For example, my module configuration form has some checkboxes, and the selected values should appear on the block.

My question is, how can I get the values from the config form in the block. 
Thanks.

Comment: A module configuration is available globally, also in a block. Could you clarify in the question (not links) where the specific issue is?

Comment: Have you tried `\Drupal::config('<config name>') `?